# \end{document} が不正な位置で認識されて、出力が途中で停止する

Tags: latex

レポートを Overleaf を使用して書いていましたところ、出力が途中で切れて、再コンパイルしても同様に出力が途中までしかされません。エラーを確認したところ、次のようなエラーが出ていました。

```
main.tex line 1164
LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 461 ended by \end{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1164 \end{document}
                     
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

正しく出力されていれば、30ページ弱のレポートなのですが、現状15ページまでで出力が止まっています。そしてこのエラーに記載されている`line 461`付近のコードが次のとおりです。

```
\subsubsection*{実行結果}
実行結果を示す.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=10cm{img/7/7-9-1.png}
    \caption{課題9の実行結果}
    \label{791}
\end{figure}
\subsubsection*{考察}
あいうえお、かきくけこ、さしすせそ
```

461行目は`\begin{figure}[H]`です。

以下参考までに package と Overleaf の設定を載せておきます。

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx, autodetect-engine]{jsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings, jlisting}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings,jlisting} %日本語コメントアウト用
\usepackage{bxtexlogo}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
```

Overleaf の設定
**Compiler** : LaTeX
**TeX Live version** : 2021

latexmkrc
これは以前[この](https://doratex.hatenablog.jp/entry/20180503/1525338512)サイトをもとに書きました。

```
$latex = 'uplatex';
$bibtex = 'upbibtex';
$dvipdf = 'dvipdfmx %O -o %D %S';
$makeindex = 'mendex -U %O -o %D %S';
$pdf_mode = 3; 
$ENV{TZ} = 'Asia/Tokyo';
$ENV{OPENTYPEFONTS} = '/usr/share/fonts//:';
$ENV{TTFONTS} = '/usr/share/fonts//:';
```

### どうか、解決方法や意見などをおねがいします。

追記
このエラーの他に、`\end{document}`に関するエラーがありましたので、追記させていただきます。

```
You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode.

\enddocument ...cument/end}\deadcycles \z@ \@@end 
                                                  
l.1164 \end{document}
                     
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
```

```
Missing } inserted.

<inserted text> 
                }
l.1164 \end{document}
                     
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

```
Emergency stop.

<*> main.tex
            
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 22090 strings out of 478997
 459884 string characters out of 5862571
 1436641 words of memory out of 5000000
 39829 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 424071 words of font info for 102 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 934 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 102i,19n,108p,579b,1745s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
Output written on output.dvi (16 pages, 40348 bytes).
```

Answer (score 4):

残念ながら LaTeX のエラーは必ずしもエラーの原因位置の特定がうまくなく，今回のように `\begin{document}` 〜 `\end{document}` はまったく関係ないのに，あたかもそこに原因があるかのようなエラーメッセージが出てしまうことがあります．

ただし，原因の位置が461行目付近という指摘は正しく，載せていただいている箇所に原因がありそうです：

```
\includegraphics[width=10cm{img/7/7-9-1.png}
```

ここで `\includegraphics` のオプション引数 `[width=10cm` が閉じていません．

```
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{img/7/7-9-1.png}
```

他に問題がなければ，これで問題なく処理が通るようになるはずです．